# Confetti particle animation in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode8, ios10, particle-system

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am trying to achieve a confetti celebration animation for a game I am working on. Something like this (but simpler):

[image]

I am trying to animate each particle with a skew animation to give the impression that each particle is a confetti falling down. Something like this:

[image]

I know that the SpriteKit particle system allows you to create a particle effect with different colour particles. However, I would like to animate each individual particle with a skew animation.

I know that it is possible to run actions on each individual particle to animate them or skew them with some sort of transformation action by using `particelAction: SKAction?`

However, I am aware that there is a bug in Xcode (v8.2.1) that means that `particelAction: SKAction?` doesn't work at all. Has this been fixed in v8.3.1? if not, then is there another way to achieve this in sprite kit? i.e. run animation or transform action on individual particles? if not is there another way all together to achieve this confetti effect with sprite kit (without using particles) which has decent performance?

Many Thanks

Comment: Another way is to use SKSpriteNodes... Which can be rendered in batches but still wont be performant as particles. Particles are lightweight. I don't know about newest version of Xcode, but on 8.2.1, `particleAction` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Negative, it still doesn't work, and Apple refuses to acknowledge that it doesn't work.  BUT what you can do, is slap an action on the emitter that constantly changes the particle texture, now it won't change each particle as it moves, but it will change with each new particle generated, hopefully giving the illusion you are looking for.